# Text classification based on optical character recognition

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, text-classification

**The problem statement:**

I need to extract the items table from receipts, like those you get in supermarkets.
It's not clean A4 invoice, where tables usually have lines.

I get the characters, along with there bounding boxes, from the OCR engine.
I then align it to the X axis.
Now, I need to find the tables.

**Why I do not take a Deep Learning Approach:**

I don't want to use deep learning for that, as it will be very huge project, very risky, very hard to debug, and I don't have enough data (few hundreds). Ho, and i don't have enough experience in training RNNs...

**I am searching for a conventional machine learning approach:**

I am considering both machine learning algorithm or my own algorithm.
I assume ML is better, but I'm not sure what algorithm will give an array of results ( = lines of items, or at least the y asix of each line).

In addition, what is the feature vector for such supervised ML? i have receipts with 2 lines and receipts with 10 lines.

By the way, when I'm saying "line" i mean line item. each item can be written in two line.

Any advice on how to solve this probelm?

Comment: It would be nice to see some exemplary data of your problem (image), the output of the OCR you are using, and the expected output of your text classification algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

> This problem falls within the realms of natural language processing / text classification

Currently these problems are solved with recurrent neural networks. You already mentioned that yourself, yet data is of the essence in these approaches. Data you do not have.

I recommend **(Natural Language Toolkit) NLTK**, a Python package that helps you do Natural Language Processing the conventional machine learning way. The following steps could form a pipeline for your problem (some exemplary data of yours would have been nice):

1. Remove punctuation (if it does not add to information gain)
2. Tokenization (Separate text into units, words or sentences)
3. Remove stop words (Swimming or running is fine for me >> Swimming Running fine)
4. Stemming or Lemmatizing (Reduce words to their stem form Swimming >> Swim)
5. Vectorize data e.g. Bag of Words (Encode the text as integers)
6. Feature extraction e.g. length of a line, key words within line, etc.
7. Pattern extraction (use your generated features to classify your line or your whole text, think about which labels your lines or your text should have)

Further reading and exemplary code with NLTK can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-nlp-for-machine-learning-d44498845d5b).

Comment: thanks! as i said, I am trying to avoid NN. I will try Rishabh Sahrawat
 answer below (see my comment there).

Answer (score 1):

In the OCR API the `isTable = true` switch triggers the table scanning logic by which you can read the table and get all the lines.

Anyways if you are using opensource it will have less accuracy. When we talk about commercial OCR like `ABBYY` or `Opentext OCR`, it will provide you upto 99%+ accuracy out of the box and it will detect tables automatically. No training, no anything, just works.

Comment: The question is about HOW to solve such problems. I'm using Google OCR to transfer image to text; but then I want to classify the data by myself.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, you have texts from the receipts. Now you can simply use LSTM or RNN, but since it is deep learning it will require few things (speaking from personal experience)-

1. It requires data which you mentioned you do not have, so if you train NN on small dataset then it will just overfit.
2. It will be better if you can increase your dataset, and once you have it either keep the number of classes to be consistent. It should not be like one class has many examples and other has only one, try to keep them consistent. If it still overfits then use Dropout and/or L2 Regualrization.

In case, deep NNs are too much and you dont' have enough data then for simplicity, start with Naive Bayes, this algorithm is super easy and effective. After preprocessing the data as mentioned by *@mrk*, just feed it to Naive Bayes and it should classify easily.

Comment: I will take this answer. Naive Bayes may help me classify to columns, and then simple algorithm that examine the price will divide it into lines.